# How can I permanently change the value of a parameter that was passed into a function in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having trouble changing the value of a passed in parameter. The **set!** function is only working on an already defined variable outside of the function. I want my function to change the values associated with the passed in parameters **without the function returning anything**.
For example:
I have the global variable deck1 and I want to make a function that adds the first element of the list to another list and then delete that element from the first list. Something like this:

```
(define deck1 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(define hand1 (list 6 7))    

(define (hit-card deck hand)                                                                                  
    (set! hand (append hand (first deck)))
    (set! deck (rest deck)))
```

If I ran the function on deck1 and hand1 `(hit-card deck1 hand1)`, I want the result to be

> deck1: 1 2 3 4 5 ==> 2 3 4 5

> hand1: 6 7       ==> 6 7 1

Comment: you meant `hand1: 6 7 ==> 6 7 1`, to be consistent with your code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is [call-by-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference), but Racket is [call-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) by default.

There are typically two ways to solve this problem in Racket.

1. Simulate call-by-reference via box and unbox

```
#lang racket

(define deck1 (box (list 1 2 3 4 5)))
(define hand1 (box (list 6 7)) )

(define (hit-card deck hand)
  (set-box! hand (cons (first (unbox deck)) (unbox hand)))
  (set-box! deck (rest (unbox deck))))

(hit-card deck1 hand1)

(unbox deck1) ; => '(2 3 4 5)
(unbox hand1) ; => '(1 6 7)
```

2. Create a small call-by-reference language embedded in your program via macro.

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (define-get/put-id id get put!)
    (define-syntax id
      (make-set!-transformer
       (lambda (stx)
         (syntax-case stx (set!)
           [id (identifier? (syntax id)) (syntax (get))]
           [(set! id e) (syntax (put! e))])))))

(define-syntax-rule (define-cbr (id arg ...) body ...)
  (begin
    (define-syntax id
      (syntax-rules ()
        [(id actual (... ...))
         (do-f (lambda () actual)
               (... ...)
               (lambda (v)
                 (set! actual v))
               (... ...))]))
    (define-for-cbr do-f (arg ...)
      ()
      body ...)))

(define-syntax define-for-cbr
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(define-for-cbr do-f (id0 id ...)
       (gens ...) body ...)
     (define-for-cbr do-f (id ...)
       (gens ... (id0 get put)) body ...)]
    [(define-for-cbr do-f ()
       ((id get put) ...) body ...)
     (define (do-f get ... put ...)
       (define-get/put-id id get put) ...
       body ...)]))
```

The program above created a new special form `define-cbr` which something like `define` in Racket but is call-by-reference.

```
(define deck1 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(define hand1 (list 6 7))

(define-cbr (hit-card deck hand)
  (set! hand (cons (first deck) hand))
  (set! deck (rest deck)))

(hit-card deck1 hand1)

deck1 ; => '(2 3 4 5)
hand1 ; => '(1 6 7)
```

More details, see https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html

Comment: This solution works. I ended up doing something a lot more simple which was to save the  first element of deck to a variable, use set! on deck (now a global variable) then appending that saved variable to the hand (as my return). I know this isn't exactly how I asked the question and doesn't follow the constraints I posted but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and wanting to do this is almost always a sign of confusion: Racket is a mostly-functional language and wants you to write programs whose component parts are functions, not procedures with arbitrary side-effects.  If the argument to the function is bound to a mutable object you *can* mutate that object.  Lists (and more generally structures made out of conses) are not mutable in Racket normally.